Upload file and relate it to a record in Salesforce using the standard API
I am trying to upload a file to salesforce using the standard API it provides and in turn relate it to a record but I always receive the same error when doing so, I am trying to do it from Postman.
The url I am using is this:
https://***.sandbox.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/ContentVersion

The header configuration is:
Authorization: Bearer *******
Content-Type: multipart/form-data

And the body of the request is (form-data):
Title: "title"
PathOnClient: "title.pdf
ContentLocation: "S"
FirstPublishLocationId: "Id of record to asociate"
entity_content(File): file.pdf

When making the request I always receive this response.
[
  {
    "message": "Multipart message must include a non-binary part",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_MULTIPART_REQUEST"
  }
]

I can't find documentation that helps me.
I appreciate your collaboration.
What I expect is a response similar to this:
{
  "id": "068Ei000002E0AHIA0",
  "success": true,
  "errors": []
}

This indicates that the file was uploaded and was related to the record indicated in "FirstPublishLocationId".
